Loading symbol in quarto interactive report using shiny
I am trying to make an interactive quarto report using shiny.
I want to display a pivot table made by pivottabler package. Now the table takes some time to render.
so the user may think its not working, I want the user to know its loading.
---
title: "Test Doc"
format:
  html:
    page-layout: full
    
server: shiny
---

```{r,message=FALSE}
#| context: setup

library(shiny)
library(pivottabler)
library(shinycssloaders)

```



```{r}

withSpinner(pivottablerOutput("pvt"))

```


```{r}
#| context: server

output$pvt = renderPivottabler({

pt <- PivotTable$new()
pt$addData(bhmtrains)
pt$addColumnDataGroups("TrainCategory")
pt$addRowDataGroups("TOC")
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="TotalTrains", summariseExpression="n()")
pt$evaluatePivot()
pivottabler(pt)

})




https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinycssloaders/readme/README.html

withSpinner() works fine for a normal shiny app but in quarto when I use it its showing a text "loading.." and it wont go even after the table appears.

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What does your current code look like? How are you using withSpinner()?

@MrFlick I updated my question with a sample code.
